# Getting prototypejs into the bower registry

Tags: prototypejs, bower

I am trying to move some code into a bower package, and my code depends on prototypejs.  Prototypejs is not in the bower registry (or it wasn't-- actually I just added it incorrectly, so this question is a bit like asking how to avoid spilling milk after it is already running off the table).  What is the proper way to go about getting it there?

I thought I could just point the registry to the prototypejs repo on github, but that resulted in a checkout of files which did not include a built prototype.js file, and it seems it can't be built with the latest version of ruby/rake.  So, one option would be to create a new github repo with the built version (downloaded from the website) and a bower.json file.  Development on prototypejs seems to have stalled (according to github), so it is unlikely the author(s) would be doing that anytime soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a repo with as you suggested for now, but still try to submit a PR on the upstream repo.

Answer (score 4):

**DISCLAIMER**

I'm beating my own drum but this should help

My PrototypeJS repo has updates in it as well as can be built using grunt and has the actual finished build files in it. Please take a look and see if it works for you.

https://github.com/jwestbrook/prototype

Comment: +1 for all the work you've been doing to maintain prototypejs (and for the link to it).  In order for bower to make use of it, the new changes would need to be tagged with a semver tag (e.g. 1.7.2).  I don't know if you've been in touch with the original author about that sort of thing.  However, I think bower users would just be interested in getting the needed version of prototype.js to satisfy a package dependency, and would not necessarily want all the files (e.g. test code) in the whole repository, so I think it is probably best to have separate repos for development and for bower.

Comment: I'll look into making the repo either smaller or being able to only tag the compiled js file for use in bower - thanks for the push.

Comment: @PaulLynch I added a bower.json file to my repo and registered it. I was able to limit it to just the 2 js files that are built.

Comment: @GN88 -- A few days earlier I also registered prototypejs-bower, which I wlll happily relinquish, but there are a couple of issues yet with your prototype.js:  1) You tagged v1.7.1, which is problematic because a "1.7.1" already exists in [sstephenson/prototype](https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/releases), and does not match your v1.7.1.  v1.7.1 should probably be v1.7.2 (or just 1.7.2 -- semver does not require the v); and 2) the sstephenson/prototype 1.7.1. should probably also be in your bower repo for people who want that version).  (Nice use of "ignore" in bower.json, BTW.)

Comment: Yes I saw that - I'm considering updating my version - but need to be sure I want to deviate from the main repo before I do so. I'm trying to get the main repo owner to do some updates and get a release pushed out. Maybe a version like 1.7.1.1?

Comment: It doesn't look to me like 1.7.1.1 is a valid semver tag (see semver.org), but see point 9 there.  You might do something like 1.7.2-beta, to allow the main repo owner to tag 1.7.2 himself if wants to.